# How to select the nth char from a string for each line in a file?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Every line has a word and a number. I need somehow to select the nth letter which all together will make a new word. For example:

```
and 3
for 3
map 2
wrestle 1

draw
```

it has to start like this

```
cat char.txt | ...
```

and I'm only allowed to use sed (no awk, perl, ...).

I know how to select all the numbers

```
sed 's/\(.*\) \(.*\)/\2/g'
```

or the text

```
sed 's/\(.*\) \(.*\)/\1/g'
```

and I was thinking about

```
cat char.txt | head -c $(sed 's/\(.*\) \(.*\)/\2/g') | tail -c 1 | sed 's/\n\//g'
```

but it won't work because it won't iterate thought all the lines and for some reason it won't even work on a single line.

Need some help and guidance pls

Ty

Comment: Are you allowed to use shell builtin commands, or are you limited to sed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while read w n; do echo -n ${w:(($n-1)):1}; done < filename
```

Output:

```
draw
```

---

```
${parameter:offset:length}: 
   Substring Expansion. Expands to up to length characters of parameter
   starting at the character specified by offset.
```

Comment: Well done. You may also want to point out what principal in bash you are making use of, such as **substring extraction** based on the **character indexes** within the string. Helpful in case they want to find the correct section of `Adv BAsh Scripting Guide` or `man bash`

Comment: note that the offset and length fields of that expansion are already treated as arithmetic expressions, so you can get away with `${word:n-1:1}`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sed script solving the puzzle, assuming that the numbers found are in the range 1—9:

```
s/ /@@@@@@@@@@ /
s/\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\).* 1$/\1/
s/\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\).* 2$/\2/
s/\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\).* 3$/\3/
s/\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\).* 4$/\4/
s/\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\).* 5$/\5/
s/\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\).* 6$/\6/
s/\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\).* 7$/\7/
s/\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\).* 8$/\8/
s/\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\).* 9$/\9/
H
$!D
${x;s/\n//g;}
```

The first lines pads the word on the current line with `@`s to ensure that there is at least 10 characters in the word field. The 9 subsequent lines replace the pattern space with the character at the given position. The `H` stores that character in the hold-space, preceded by a newline character. Unless the last line has been read, we discard the pattern space and start-over again. If the last line has been read, we exchange the pattern space with the hold space, which holds the desired word spammed with newline characters, which we remove.

Saving this in a file `script.sed` we obtain

```
% sed -f script.sed < data
draw
```

The charming exercise of implementing a version supporting character offsets in the range 1—19 is left as an exercise to the reader.

We can more easily solve this puzzle with `awk`:

```
% awk '{answer=answer substr($1,$2,1)}END{print(answer)}' < data
draw
```

Comment: @TomFenech As a vengeance, I wrote a `sed` script solving the puzzle. :-)

Comment: We hereby re-define the the "Rube Goldberg" idiom, the "Grünewald-Fenech". That's pretty cool.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It is really fun to solve programming puzzles with sed. It is someone seen on CG, see for instance “[do we sink or swim](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/23259/do-we-sink-or-swim)” where the sed-submission beats submissions in C, scala and Python!

Comment: I commend the effort and will take a look. I enjoy these type of problems immensely. There is a similar (not puzzle, but challenge), annually regarding code obscuration. It takes a clever mind to understand how to skin a cat 9 different ways :)

Answer (score 0):

using only sed (sorry to avoid the cat char.txt :-;

```
sed -n ':a
/1$/ !{
   s/.//
   h
   s/.* \([0-9]\)$/\1/
   y/98765432/87654321/
   G
   s/\(.\)\n\(.*\) [0-9]/\2 \1/
   b a
   }
s/\(.\).*/\1/p' char.txt
```

Assuming you only take column 1 to 9 (single digit) but could be extended with adaptation to "huge number".
It also, by 'simplicity' write the word 1 char per line (so verticaly). Could also be modified bu overload the code.

**Explaination**

principle: if last digit is not 1, remove first char and decrease by 1. If it is equal to 1, print the 1st char of the line.

- test if last digit is 1 by `/1$/`
- Decrease is done by the translation `y/98765432/87654321/`
- remove of first char by `s/.//`
- other is presentation using working and holding buffer (to modify only last digit part) by copying the line, leave only the digit, decrease, add the original line and rearrange new digit in place of last old one
- reaching digit = 1, in does not enter to the process and keep only 1st char, then print it by `s/\(.\).*/\1/p`